# Using KQL in Sharepoint online 2013

Tags: 2013, query, kql

I'm using `ContentTypeId:0x0108* Path:{Site.Url} AssignedTo:{User.Name}Status<>Completed` to sort out all completed tasks. But it does not work.

If I use only `NOT` or `-Completed` it works, but it also sort out all completed tasks in every column. Is there a way to only sort out Tasks in the Task Status column?